# How to handle exceptions while inserting a document into Mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, exception

My code:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("mydb");

    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("myColl");

    Document document = new Document();
    document.put("empID", 1);
    document.put("empName", "ABC");
    try{
    collection.insert(document);
    } catch (MongoException e) {
      system.out.println(e);
      }
```

For the above code,I have tried to handle with the try/catch block.But unable to handle exceptions.

Can anyone please help me out about how to handle exceptions if suppose the db name (or) colection name is incorrect .

Comment: what jind of exception you get?

Comment: I have kept some incorrect db name and tried to handle the exception but my program flow is coming out of the catch block.

Comment: add the try {  Statement on the top of your code snipped.